# How can I share a database connection across a forked process in Perl?

Tags: perl, db2, fork

I made the following programs in Perl before:

```
my $db = DBconnection with DB2

if ($pid = fork()) {
    #parent
} else {
    #child
    $db->execute("SELECT ****");
    exit;
}

wait();
$db->execute("SELECT ****");
```

I thought that it waited for the end of the child process to have wanted to do it and would operate it for DB by a pro-process.

In addition, DB is not connected to the contents of the error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff you must do to allow a child process to use its parent's DBI handle.  See this article on Perl Monks about [DBI, fork, and clone](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=594175).

Answer (score 1):

Try including this line of code in your child block:

```
$db->{InactiveDestroy} = 1;
```